# How to disable a swap file configured by systemd, via Ansible?

Tags: centos, systemd, fstab, swap, ansible

What's the best way to disable swap entirely on a fleet of GNU/Linux hosts, using systemd and Ansible?

For whatever reason some of my virtual machines have a swap file configured in their `/etc/fstab`, which gets automatically picked up at boot by `systemd-fstab-generator` like this:

```
$ cat /run/systemd/generator/swapfile.swap
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)

[Swap]
What=/swapfile
```

Some services running on those machines get terminally slow when using the swap file, for various reasons, so I need to prevent them from using it. My version of systemd doesn't yet include [`MemorySwapMax`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#MemorySwapMax=bytes).

I'd like to avoid messing up with `/etc/fstab` and I don't mind having those swap files left in place.

For context, I'm using ansible-3.0.0, ansible-base-2.10.6; the machines are CentOS 7, with systemd 219.

Comment: Just delete the swap line from /etc/fstab if you don't want it.  Also you realize that this means you will just run out of ram and the OOM-killer will kill some memory hogging processes?

Comment: @psusi I don't want to change `/etc/fstab` with ansible. And yes, my goal is to get those processes killed as fast as possible by the kernel.

Comment: How convenient. Linus Torvalds just proclaimed that "swapfiles just aren't normal". https://lkml.org/lkml/2021/3/3/1332 I swear there was no coordination. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let systemd do its thing by default and then just revert it with another systemd unit immediately afterwards.

If you check with `systemd show swapfile.swap`, you'll see all the unit does is to run `swapon` on that file. When you issue `swapoff` manually, the swap will reappear at the next boot.

Running `swapoff` immediately after `swapon` will only take a fraction of a second because there's nothing to move back from disk to memory. However you must make sure you run `swapoff` *after* `swapon`, and you can tell systemd to do so with `After=local-fs.target`.

Place your unit file as a j2 template named `noswap.service.j2` in the `templates/` directory for your playbook or role:

```
{{ ansible_managed|comment }}

[Unit]
Description=Disable swapfile
Documentation=man:swapon(8) man:systemd.swap(5)
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/swapoff -a

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Have something like this in your playbook or role:

```yaml
---
- name: Your playbook

  tasks:
    - name: Write noswap systemd service config file
      template:
        src: noswap.service.j2
        dest: /etc/systemd/system/noswap.service
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0644
      notify: Enable noswap service

  handlers:
    - name: Enable noswap service
      systemd:
        name: noswap
        state: started
        enabled: true
        daemon_reload: true
```

After the first time, the service will be started during boot, so the `state: started` should prevent it from being issued again every time you run ansible.